# PHP - Sort Array By SubArray Value By Maintaining original Array key

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I would like to Sort an Array with its sub array value ("Name") but keeping its original array key.

default Array:

```
Array (
    [251] => Array
        (
            [color] => 
            [name] => 8
            [nbr] => 1
            [url_name] => taille-8
            [meta_title] => 
        )

    [323] => Array
        (
            [color] => 
            [name] => 7
            [nbr] => 2
            [url_name] => taille-7
            [meta_title] => 
        )

    [127] => Array
        (
            [color] => 
            [name] => 34
            [nbr] => 2
            [url_name] => taille-34
            [meta_title] => 
        )
);
```

By using array_multisort, I can able to get following Array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [color] => 
            [name] => 7
            [nbr] => 2
            [url_name] => taille-7
            [meta_title] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [color] => 
            [name] => 8
            [nbr] => 1
            [url_name] => taille-8
            [meta_title] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [color] => 
            [name] => 34
            [nbr] => 2
            [url_name] => taille-34
            [meta_title] => 
        )
);
```

But what i need is,

```
Array(
    [323] => Array
        (
            [color] => 
            [name] => 7
            [nbr] => 2
            [url_name] => taille-7
            [meta_title] => 
        )

    [251] => Array
        (
            [color] => 
            [name] => 8
            [nbr] => 1
            [url_name] => taille-8
            [meta_title] => 
        )

    [127] => Array
        (
            [color] => 
            [name] => 34
            [nbr] => 2
            [url_name] => taille-34
            [meta_title] => 
        )
);
```

Thanks in adv :)

Comment: check usort function

Comment: please add `array_multisort` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$arr` being your  array:

```
//obtain list of values to sort by
foreach ($arr as $id => $value) {
    $names[$id] = $value['name'];
}
$keys = array_keys($arr);
array_multisort(
    $names, SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, $arr, $keys
);
$result = array_combine($keys, $arr);
```

You were probably missing the last step combining the array with given keys.

Comment: I have checked your code, Does not gives the result

Comment: @NarayanBhandari check again, please: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce77839c6d484a07796cec18ef2a5a3ba17fcd4d

Answer (score 3):

I would go with [uasort](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.uasort.php), it looks much simpler to me:

```
// $arr is your Array
uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
  return $a['name'] - $b['name'];
});
```

Here is an example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a9f2d1e9702834b3a35206125429739222770301

Answer (score 1):

`$arr` assuming your array containing numeric keys and sort it by using `array_multisort`.

`array_multisort` will return sorted array. 
`array_combine` will combine your original keys with sorted array.

**Use:**

```
$result = array_sort_by_column_preserve_keys($arr);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);echo '</pre>';
```

**Method :**

```
function array_sort_by_column_preserve_keys($arr) {
    $ar2 = [];
    foreach($arr as $key => $sub) {
        $ar2[ $key ] = $sub;
    }
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    array_multisort($ar2, SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, $arr, $keys);
    return $result = array_combine($keys, $arr);
}
```

Comment: You could have edited my answer, since it's basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
$array=array(
    "251" => array(
        "color" => "",
        "name" => 8,
        "nbr" => 1,
        "url_name" => "taille-8",
        "meta_title" => ""),

    "323" => array(
        "color" => "",
        "name" => 7,
        "nbr" => 2,
        "url_name" => "taille-7",
        "meta_title" => ""),
    "127" => array(
        "color" => "",
        "name" => 34,
        "nbr" => 2,
        "url_name" => "taille-34",
        "meta_title" => ""),
    );
function swapArray( &$arr,$firstPos,$secondPos){
    //echo PHP_EOL."swap: ".$firstPos.", ".$secondPos.PHP_EOL;
    foreach($arr[$firstPos] as $k=>$v){
        //echo PHP_EOL.$k." => ".$v.PHP_EOL;
        $tmp=$v;
        $arr[$firstPos][$k]=$arr[$secondPos][$k];
        $arr[$secondPos][$k]=$tmp;
    }
}
    var_dump($array);

    $keys=array(); // store all key values
    $num=count($array);

    foreach($array as $key=>$tmpArray)
        $keys[]=$key;

    //var_dump($keys);

    for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++){
        for($j=$i+1; $j<$num; $j++){
            if($array[$keys[$i]]["name"]>$array[$keys[$j]]["name"]){
                swapArray($array,$keys[$i],$keys[$j]);
            }
        }
    }


    var_dump($array);
```